# None of the filesystem seems to work after grub rescue error

Tags: grubrescue

After accidently entering into Windows system recovery, I shut down immediately by long pressing the power button. It shows
error: no such partition 
Entering rescue mode
Grub rescue.
I had this problem before, then I did
LS (hdx,msdosx) and the 'set' codes. Then insmod normal.
At that time it worked. But now all the partitions shows unknown filesystem, after the code insmod normal. 
Please help.

Comment: Boot into a live session and create a screenshot of GParted, then post it here. Furthermore, post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (that's a lowercase `L`, in the end). This will show whether your partitions still exist.

Comment: I don't have a live CD ...

Comment: Use a different live medium like a live USB stick. The medium you installed the system with probably offers a live session.

Comment: Buy if I have to make a live USB stick, I will have to use my computer, in that case, I don't have another PC. Is there any way that I could make it from an Android phone ?